# Excel filtering comma-separated values separately

Tags: excel

[image: I am trying to filter a column in excel so I can select]

Is there a possibility to filter for the three terms "Hallo", "Test" and "Welt" separately, without using the search function.

Comment: You can use a 'Contains' text filter, if that's what you mean?

Comment: @Rory No not quite, what I want is that I can select the words like I can select "Test, Hallo, Welt" at the moment.

Comment: You can't do that with a normal filter since the values separately does not exist. You only have one that is all three. You could create a own filter dropdown thing, but I belive that will be a lot of work.